# jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i am using jquery validation as follow

```
var validator=$("#myform")
    .validate({
        rules: {
                   field1: { required: true },
                   field2: { required: true },
                   field3: { required: true },
                   field4: { required: true }

            }
});
```

field1, field2 are in tab0 and field3,field4 in tab1

If i click in tab1 without fill field1, field2 and fill field3, field4 the validation is true.

I guess in this case field1,field2 are hidden because of tabs.

Here is my form

```
<form  id="myform"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="myaction.php" >
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab-1">tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2">tab2</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div id="tab-1">  
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />     
        <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" />     
    </div>

    <div id="tab-2">  
        <input type="text" name="field3" id="field3" />     
        <input type="text" name="field4" id="field4" />     
    </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="save">
                <img src="/admin/graphics/icons/disk.gif" alt=""/>Save
    </button>
    </form>
```

How can i solve this.Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: @Pekka : the form as you requested

Comment: I don't understand - no validation takes place when you switch between tabs, that works as designed, doesn't it?

Comment: Is the desired function for all four fields to be validated when the submit button is pressed, whether or not their tab(s) are visible?

Comment: @Pekka: yes when switch tab no validation takes place.But if you dont fill all requires fileds in the first tab and switch to second when submit validates only fileds in second tab.Any forgotten field in tab1 does not validate.thats the problem

Comment: @ntan it might have to do with the script you use for tabbing rather than the validator plugin

Comment: @Pekka : i use jquery ui tabs, which is great

Comment: @ntan does it work without the tabs?

Comment: return false; if fields are not filled . if empty.